# Unable to call otbApplication from python

Tags: python, ubuntu, orfeo-toolbox

I have been tryng to use some of OTB functions from python, but i am unable to import the module (otbApplication), even after to adding the PYTHONPATH to my basrc file. I am working in Ubuntu14.04, and i have been able to call the same functions from QGIS, but not from python, neither from my IDE (pycharm) or the command line.

What should i do?

Answer (score 1):

as a quick and dirty workaround, you could try to launch it using subprocess.call() with full path to your otbcli_ApplicationName .

Otherwise, if you compiled it from scratch, make sure that OTB_WRAP_PYTHON is set to true in your ccmake file.

Comment: I will try that, is a very good idea. I did not compiled it, i am using the precompiled packages from ubuntugis ppa